# ¿Como sumar inputs dinamicamente y que aparezca el resultado en otro input?

Tags: javascript

Saludos, estoy buscando la manera de sumar el monto de un input, tantas veces yo le diga en otro input. El problema surge que debo sacar el 20% de ese monto y sumarselo cuando anteriormente haya sumado el monto del input 3 veces. Dare un ejemplo:

input de cantidad: 9
input de monto: 10.000 $

Primera multiplicacion: 10.000*3 = 30.000

Porcentaje monto inicial: 10.000 * 0.2

Segunda multiplicacion: 12.000*3 = 36.000

Porcentaje segundo monto inicial: 12.000 * 0.2

Tercera Multiplicacion: 14.400*3 = 43.200

Total de costo: 109.200 $

Para ser mas claro necesito que saque el porcentaje cada 3 montos, asi: 
10.000, 10.000, 10.000, 12.000, 12.000, 12.000, 14.400, 14.400, 14.400, y luego que sume todos esos valores, sabiendo que en el input que llame arriba cantidad pueden haber valores desde 1-50. Me esta costando desarrollar el algoritmo, no consigo la forma, a quien me pueda ayudar muchas gracias. Hasta ahora esto es lo que medio llevo de codigo:

```
  <script>
      var aumento = 0.2;
      var aumentaCada = 3;
      var cantidad = $("#num").val();
      var monto = $("#input7").val();

    for(var i=0; i< cantidad ; i++){
      if((i>0) && (i % aumentaCada)==0){
        monto = monto * (1+aumento);
      }
      var total = monto * cantidad;
    }

    $("#total").val(total);

  </script>
```

Comment: Agrega  a tu pregunta el codigo de lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Einer alli esta lo que llevo de codigo, pero no me muestra nada en el input ni da algun error en consola.

Answer (score 2):

debes de revisar bien tu algoritmo, raya primero en papel para crear la forma mas eficiente para poder realizar el calculo, lo otro es entender bien el concepto de porcentajes como se maneja. cuando tienes claro el algoritmo puedes pasar esto a código y hacerlo mas fácil.

```
           $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("button").click(function () {

                        var cantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
                        var monto = $("#monto").val();
                        if (cantidad !== "" && monto !== "") {
                            var residuo = cantidad % 3;
                            var multiplos = parseInt((cantidad / 3), 10);
                            var total = 0;
                            for (i = 1; i <= multiplos; i++) {
                                total += (monto * 3);
                                monto = monto * 1.2;
                            }
                            if (residuo > 0) {
                                total += (monto * residuo);
                            }
                            console.log("TOTAL:" + total);
                            $("#total").val(total);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

De ti depende si quieres aprender o solo solucionar un ejercicio. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, hare lo que me dices carlos, ahora una ultima pregunta, no puedo hacer que el total me aparezca dinamicamente en el input? sin necesidad de que le de click a un boton "calcular"?

Comment: @LuisHenriquez Si claro, puedes utilizar métodos de invocación de funciones como onchange, onfocus, o $( "#monto" ).focus(function() { todo depende de como y en que momento quieres que funcione, OJO debes de validar que contengan datos y validos para hacer operaciones.

Comment: Va a funcionar solo en un formulario de apertura de cursos, donde yo ingrese la cantidad de cuotas que tendra el curso y el monto de la primera cuota, y a partir de alla que haga los calculos del porcentaje y las sumas para que me de el total de el monto del curso. En que parte podria usar .focus? en el input de monto o en los dos?

Comment: Si carlos la validacion si la tengo hecha!

Answer (score 2):

Te dare un proceso mas corto que la primera respuesta:

```html
<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  cantidad: <input type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad"><br>
  monto: <input type="number" id="monto" name="monto"><br>

  <button onclick="calcula()">Calcular</button>


  <script>
  var acumulado=parseInt(0);
  function calcula(){
   var cantidad = parseInt($("#cantidad").val());
   var monto = parseInt($("#monto").val());
   var vecesPorcentaje = Math.floor(cantidad/3);
   var vecesSobrantes = cantidad-(vecesPorcentaje*3);

   for(var i = 0; i<vecesPorcentaje; i++){
     acumulado = acumulado+(monto*3);
     monto = monto+(monto*0.2);
   }
   acumulado = acumulado+(monto*vecesSobrantes);
   alert(acumulado);
  }

  </script>
```

te adjunto el codepen para que compruebes que funciona:
[calcula porcentaje](https://codepen.io/andreschica/pen/brobbB)